# More visible styling for disabled actions in the mod menu

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, design, beta-phase

The “mod” button on posts brings up a dialog box with actions selected by a radio button.

[image: mod dialog screenshot]

For this particular post, the actions “convert to edit”, “show flag history” and “show review history” are disabled (because they are not applicable). However, the styling barely reflects this. (I initially thought the styling didn't reflect this. On second examination, the button is a slightly lighter shade of grey.)

Please make it more visually evident when actions are disabled.

My request applies to beta sites, and any other site where this is an issue).

Comment: While we're at it… *convert to comment* and *convert to edit* could be disabled automatically if the post has no valid owner. That non-styled error message on a separate page still gets me every time.

Comment: And why is *timeline* not an option? Just like *show flag history* and *show review history* it takes you to a separate page without causing any side-effects. So either put those three as links below, or make *timeline* another radio button.

Comment: I just ran into this (on a graduated site, Mi Yodeya) when I tried to send a mod message from a meta profile instead of the main one.  It sure *looked* like I could, but I wasn't able to click that option.  If there's a visual difference there it was too subtle for me.

Comment: I could've sworn we used to disable and grey out unavailable items.